# Removing part of a string and use it to intersect with another dataframe

Tags: r, regex

I have two dataframes that I am trying to compare and find their overlap based on a column of strings. However, some of them have an extra and unnecessary addition to them. For example, 'C8 H12 O1' in one df should be equal to 'C8 H12 O1 Na1'. I want to remove the 'Na1" from any string that might have it.

I figured that I need to use regex for this, but I can't get a handle on out to do that. I figured out how to find their overlap % by using this example code -

```
list1 <- c('C8 H12 O1 Na1', 'C15 H20 O7 Na1', 'C18 H24 O6', 'C24 H32 O9 Na1')
list2 <- c('C8 H12 O1', 'C19 H26 O7 Na1', 'C18 H24 O6', 'C24 H32 O9 Na1')
df1 <- data.frame(list1)
colnames(df1) <- "Composition"
df2 <- data.frame(list2)
colnames(df2) <- "Composition"
paste0(round(100*length(intersect(df1$Composition, 
                                  df2$Composition))/nrow(df2)), "%")

# [1] "50%"
```

The real percentage should technically be 75% due to the first entry having the "same" string minus the Na1.

Comment: Show us an example of input (we need to understand what is an extra column) and its respective example of output. And, if possible, show some research on regular expressions as a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could ignore the `Na1` by throwing a `gsub` around it.

```
paste0(round(100*length(intersect(gsub(" Na1", "", df1$Composition), 
                                  gsub(" Na1", "", df2$Composition)))/nrow(df2)), "%")
# [1] "75%"
```

Comment: This worked. I also changed it a bit so that the % similarity made more sense. 
    intersectlength <- round(length(intersect(gsub(" Na1", "", df1$Composition), 
                                  gsub(" Na1", "", df2$Composition))))
    paste0((intersectlength/(length(df1$Composition) + length(df2$Composition) - 
    intersectlength)*100), "%")'''

Answer (score 0):

You could use `startsWith`.  The following adds up all of the matching combinations and divides by the length of `list2`...

```
sum(outer(list1, list2, startsWith),
    outer(list2, list1, startsWith)) / length(list2)

[1] 0.75
```